# "Could not deduce" error from "fromIntegral"

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell and I have made this function which should (I haven't actually tested it yet) read [varints](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?hl=da#varints):

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Binary

getNum :: Get Int
getNum = do
    l <- getWord8
    let v = fromIntegral (clearBit l 7) :: Int
    if testBit l 7
        then do m <- getNum
                return $ v .|. shiftL m 7
        else return v
```

It compiles fine, but I would like this to be able to read any kind of integer, not just `Int`, so I changed it to this:

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Binary

getNum :: (Bits a, Integral a) => Get a
getNum = do
    l <- getWord8
    let v = fromIntegral (clearBit l 7) :: a
    if testBit l 7
        then do m <- getNum
                return $ v .|. shiftL m 7
        else return v
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Num a2) arising from a use of ‘fromIntegral’
from the context (Bits a, Integral a)
  bound by the type signature for
             getNum :: (Bits a, Integral a) => Get a
  at test.hs:12:11-39
Possible fix:
  add (Num a2) to the context of
    an expression type signature: a2
    or the inferred type of v :: a1
    or the type signature for getNum :: (Bits a, Integral a) => Get a
In the expression: fromIntegral (clearBit l 7) :: a
In an equation for ‘v’: v = fromIntegral (clearBit l 7) :: a
In the expression:
  do { l <- getWord8;
       let v = ...;
       if testBit l 7 then
           do { m <- getNum;
                .... }
       else
           return v }
```

I can't really figure out what the error message is trying to tell me and I cannot find anything conclusive searching for it. Could someone please explain to me why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove `:: a` from the `fromIntegral` line:

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Binary

getNum :: (Bits a, Integral a) => Get a
getNum = do
    l <- getWord8
    let v = fromIntegral (clearBit l 7)
    if testBit l 7
        then do m <- getNum
                return $ v .|. shiftL m 7
        else return v
```

#### Explanation

Assume again the following line for a second:

```
    let v = fromIntegral (clearBit l 7) :: a
```

At this point, `a` is another independent type variable and has nothing to do with the `a` from `(Bits a, Integral a) => Get a`. Therefore, `a` doesn't have the `Num` or `Bit` constraint, although the type checker should get it right, since you later `return v`.

However, since you're missing constraints, it assumes that you actually know what you do and assumes an arbitrary type. Since `fromIntegral` *requires* an `Integral` instance, it fails. If you add those constraints again locally, it will compile again:

```
let v = fromIntegral (clearBit l 7) :: (Integral a) => a
```

But still, `a` at this point isn't the type variable in your functions signature. You would need the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension for this. But even better, just scrap the local expression signature, as GHC will infer the types correctly.